# Swift - Как сделать активным searchBar сразу после перехода на Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, search

Подскажите, как можно сделать активным searchBar (searchController.searchBar) и клавиатуру сразу после перехода на viewController с этим searchBar?

*searchBar создан программно.
P.s. подсказали becomeFirstResponder, но не помогло.
Каким образом это необходимо сделать?

Добавляю searchController следующим образом:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Setup the Search Controller
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Поиск организаций"
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

    // Setup the Navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
}
```

На данные момент после перехода экран выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После перехода на viewController, он должен выглядеть следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как добавляете, в каком виде он сейчас при открытии? Нужно больше информации.

Comment: Здравствуйте, добавил информацию в текст вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом случае нужно немного покостылить.

Сначала в viewDidappear указать:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    searchController.isActive = true
}
```

Указываете delegate:

```
searchController.delegate = self
//для контроллера UISearchControllerDelegate
```

Метод делегата:

```
func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1, execute: { [weak self] in
        self?.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder() 
    })
}
```

После этого при открытии контроллера поиск будет активным.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но метод didPresentSearchController, как willPresentSearchController вызывается после нажатия на searchBar, но не после перехода на контроллер.

Comment: @IliaFedorov 
    searchController.isActive = true указали?

Comment: да) Создал тестовый проект и залил на github. Вот: https://github.com/AdilisIV/SearchBarTest/blob/master/CustomSegueTest/SearchViewController.swift

Comment: @IliaFedorov ну Вы же сделали не так как написано в ответе. Не в viewWillAppear, а в viewDidAppear. не willPresentSearchController, а didPresentSearchController

Comment: Ох, я извиняюсь за свою глупость. Все работает, спасибо! Git репозиторий оставлю, может кому пригодится)